# How to protect privacy vis-a-vis sending resume to potential employer?

Tags: united-states, california, privacy

How can I protect the personal information contained within my C.V., cover letter, letters of recommendation from unauthorized sharing?

I have been a victim of identity theft, so I seek to now find ways of limiting the exposure of my personal information to any entity I come across, including employers.

I thought it would be to my benefit to have a confidentiality disclaimer page stating that I do not consent to the sharing of this information without my prior approval. I've heard of employers selling applicant information, or sharing it, and I just want a way to protect against that; if that's even possible.

Comment: What personal information do you include in your resume? Your name, contact information, and basic employment information should not need protecting, per se. If you're concerned specifically about a phone number, e-mail address, or mailing address, we can talk about getting other phone lines, other e-mail addresses, and P.O. boxes. If you're worried about contacts, it's not considered bad form to simply add "available upon request" and wait for a written (contingent) offer. These materials are like advertisements - you should want lots of people to see them.

Answer (score 2):

For sensitive information, you could send an electronic copy via a shareable link in a cloud drive service (Google Drive, Box, etc.) and then restrict the link to the recruiter's email or make it a temporary link.

Alternatively, you could use the following code in Adobe Acrobat to make a resume PDF expire at a certain time (credit at the bottom):

While in Acrobat, select **Set Page Action** from the Document menu. In the **Page Actions** dialog, select When this happens -> Page Open -> Add. For the type of action, select **JavaScript**. Click on **Edit** to add your script. Copy and paste this script into the editor window:

```
// PDF JavaScript to make it a "TRIAL EDITION". 

// Set the date you would like it to EXPIRE ON. 
var d1 = util.scand("mm/dd/yy", "7/1/04"); 

// Let the script do the work... 
var expire_on_X_days_left = 0; 
var d2 = new Date(); 
var diff = (d2.valueOf() - d1.valueOf()) / 1000; 
var daysleft = ((diff / 60) / 60) / 24; 
if( daysleft > expire_on_X_days_left || daysleft == expire_on_X_days_left ) 
{ 
// Comment this line if you would like it to NOT MAKE A BEEP! 
app.beep(1); 
// Uncomment this if you would like a message to be displayed. 
//    app.alert("This document cannot be viewed anymore."); 
this.closeDoc(); 
}
```

> JavaScript walk-thru adapted from this [answer](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Document_Imaging/Adobe_Acrobat/Q_21757762.html), by Brian (thedude at bri1.com);